# Как правильно убрать / отключить тег br в медиа правил?

Tags: html, css, html5, scss, sass

Нужно в медиа правил после разрешение 576px убрать тег **br** где он был, в scss убираю через свойство **display:none**, как убирается перенос текста, то нету пробела между словами ***"стилизованные 3D-модели" и "разной сложности"*** как на скриншоте показано. Однако если мой кусок фрагмента кода который прикрепляю здесь в сообщение пробелы есть, а в консоли нету. Нужно ли еще какие та свойства прописать кроме **display:none**? Спасибо

[image: нету пробела где был br]

```css
br {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
 <section class="learn">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="title title_center">Чему ты <br>научишься?</h2>
            <div class="learn__wrapper">
                <div class="learn__item">
                    <div class="learn__round">
                        <div class="learn__number">1</div>
                        <div class="learn__orange"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="learn__descr">С нуля создавать стилизованные <br>3D-модели архитектуры, окружения и персонажей</div>
                </div>
                <div class="learn__item">
                    <div class="learn__round">
                        <div class="learn__number">2</div>
                        <div class="learn__round-orange"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="learn__descr">Настраивать базовые материалы создавать простые текстуры</div>
                </div>

                <div class="learn__item">
                    <div class="learn__round">
                        <div class="learn__number">3</div>
                        <div class="learn__round-orange"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="learn__descr">Настраивать сцену, освещение и камеру для рендеринга</div>
                </div>
                <div class="learn__item">
                    <div class="learn__round">
                        <div class="learn__number">4</div>
                        <div class="learn__round-orange"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="learn__descr">Создавать анимацию разной <br>сложности</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, но display: none; работает абсолютно.  Изучите подробнее страницу через F12. И нужно Полный код выкладывать, а не вот это вот ...

Comment: Спасибо, Пересмотрю либо просто ограничу ширину через модификатор и не буду парится. Верстаю по БЭМ и через scss, если код полный выкладывать, там идет амперсанд вложенность, даже поправляю на обычную вложенность классов, код тут почему то не срабатывает, подумал достаточно будет кусочка рабочего) Учту на будущее